# Center a div inline

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Still new to html. Trying to center this subscription box under the bottom of the list. Pretty sure I've found the relevant div, but

```
style="margin: 0, auto;"
```

makes no change whatsoever.

How do I do this?

The screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZtsL.png

Comment: For starters you don't need a comma after `0`. `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: Remove `,`  it should be `margin:0 auto`

Comment: Please add your HTML code here instead of sharing a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Can try these:

I'm assuming the highlighted line is the one you'd like to modify.
If you use the id="secondary" selector you are guaranteed to be targeting a single element as id is required to be unique on each page. So if your id="secondary" here are a few things to try in the CSS

```
#secondary{
    float:center;
}
```

or

```
#secondary{
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Let us know how it goes and what worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, please remove the comma from your style:

```
style="margin: 0 auto;"
```

To make this work, your div should ideally have a fixed width, so that it can actually center to the parent container.
Also make sure that your div is `display:block;`. That should do the trick.